# Should we have a specific "Retag Request" thread?

Tags: discussion, tags

Every retag request (and re-request) takes another Q&A post which clutters up meta with a very short-lived and repetitive process.

Would it be better to **create a generic retag request "question"** and add a new answer for each specific request? Answer voting can take care of opinions and comments can take care of what little meta discussion might be needed for each request.

As the "retag question" becomes too long to effectively manage, it can be closed as "no longer relevant" and a new one created (monthly?, periodically?).

Thoughts?

Comment: It would be better, if we got that tag black list, so the mods do not need to do it again and again and again! (Why do I have the feeling that I've written something similar not long ago? After watching *Matrix* déjà vus frighten me...)

Comment: Agree it would be *better*. My "suggestion" was in the context of the framework we have to work with today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There used to be an old dog by the name of [The Great Tagging Reorg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg-closed). It would be one massive canine where each of the answers were requests.

But then, it was put down in order for other puppies to run and have their individual say:

> Please add new requests as new items, tagged with the site, for example:

Reason being that it got so long in the tooth that it was becoming something of a right old mess keeping up and checking the status of retag requests.

Guess the individual [retag requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request) were easier to pin down and class as **[status-completed]** while at the same time allowing for more actual scrutiny/discussion on the individual tags.

Comment: I can't tell from that post why it wasn't effective or why it was closed/locked.

Comment: It got messy. That's pretty much it.

Comment: Fair enough. That was an attempt at *massive* re-org. But now that it's "done" and requests are a bit more routine, I was thinking a single thread might be a better mechanism.

Comment: As requests are completed, the answer can be deleted to keep the content of the thread to *outstanding* requests only.

Answer (score 2):

To put more context on @random's random answer; indeed, it simply doesn't "work" (IMO) as a single discussion. With separate questions it can be discussed and tracked separately, and I can see [the pending queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request+-status-declined+-status-completed) easily.

With the individual question, it quickly became impossible to see new posts, or even properly track requests that were known about.

They aren't high volume, so IMO it isn't worth trying to "fix" anything here.

Comment: The status-completed becomes status-we-need-another-retag in about a week.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.